Why is pgfplots.colorbrewer conflited with \addplot options?
I would like to use colorbrewer, but it seems that it is conflicted with options in \addplot command. For example, if I use some options (e.g., domain=-2:2), it will adopt black color, and ignore the cycle list/Set1-5.
Is it a bug or feature? How to handle this? The code on overleaf:

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, cycle list/Set1-5,}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[cycle list name=Set1-5,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$]
        \addplot{x^3};
        \addplot[domain=-2:2]{x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


It is a feature. To append styles, we should use \addplot+.
